# How can I capture window area that is playing a video and display the area in another window in Linux

Tags: linux, video, lxde, openbox

I'd like to have a small video window "Always on top" of other windows in my LXDE which would display just the video area I have previously chosen in another window, e.g. Chrome displaying edX video page.

Comment: I think VLC can capture desktop. At the moment I can only confirm it can do this on Windows. I don't know if there are options to crop while capturing, still there are options to crop while displaying. If I'm right and anyone wants to turn the idea into a proper answer, please go ahead.

Comment: About "Chrome displaying edX video page": check if Picture-in-Picture works with edX videos.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: With the "Picture-in-Picture Extension" installed, it does work with edX videos. Thanks for the tip! I'm still looking for a solution.